# Adding a video to Bootstrap Jumbotron

Tags: html, css

I am trying to embed a video inside of a bootstrap jumbotron, and it doesn't appear anywhere with the code I currently have. What am I missing?

```
<section class="jumbotron text-center">
            <video id="video-background" preload muted autoplay loop>
                        <source src="/images/vacation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album example</h1>
                <p class="lead text-muted">Something short </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Main call to action</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Secondary action</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and also my CSS

```
#video-background {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: -100;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the jumbotron position relative, the it's child (the video) I set to absolute.  This means the absolute coordinates will be relative to the jumbotron itself.  I set position relative on the jumbotron container for the sole purpose of increasing it's z-index to sit on top of the video.  Hid the overflow on the jumbotron so the video didn't extend outside of the boundaries.

Enjoy me brapping around during winter a few years ago!

```css
#video-background {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
        }

.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="jumbotron text-center">
  <video id="video-background" preload muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://james-allen.ca/brap.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album example</h1>
    <p class="lead text-muted">Something short </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Main call to action</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2">Secondary action</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```